# express.js, How can I distinguish http server and https server?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to log a information in console when the server is started.

the information like this:

`http server is started, address: http://127.0.0.1:2223`

`https server is started, address: https://127.0.0.1:2222`

here is my code:

```
httpsServer.on('listening', () => onListening(httpsServer));
httpServer.on('listening', () => onListening(httpServer));

function onListening(server: http.Server | https.Server) {
  const addr = server.address();
  let protocoal: string;

  //Here, I want to distinguish https and http server.
  //Is there nodeJs/express.js way rather than pass a parameter way?
  //like `server.secure` api?

  protocol = server.secure ? 'https' : 'http';

  console.log(protocoal + ' server is started，address：' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express has [req.secure](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.secure) which is a boolean property that is true if a TLS connection is established.

Comment: That's not available in the 'listening' event, though, which is what the OP asked about.